# RXTX x64 and x86

Tags: java, windows, applet, rxtx

I've a software where I use RXTXcomm.jar on an applet java and inside applet I'm communicating with port serial, so, I need to communicate and it works with 2 versions, x86 and x64, but RXTXcomm.jar has the same name to 2 files,
How can I use both jars in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar (RXTXcomm.jar) is the same as offers the API. The difference is the native implementation (dll in Windows), so you can try to generate different applets for different platforms supported and let user choose the right one. Another way is trying to bundle all native libraries and could work. (checked rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2.zip version contents).

Comment: Thank you for attention, I tried to use rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2.zip in my applet but I don't know the reason, didn't work for me, only 2.2 version, and I put specific dlls in each Windows, 
and in my case,
I need RXTXcomm.jar inside my project, is a web project and it needs RXTXcomm.jar together with applet.jar and applet.class in same path, so, in my project has RXTXcomm.jar for x86 and I need both versions, RXTXcomm x86 and x64 together to run on both Windows

Comment: Not checked 2.2 version, but if the jar is the same (I suppose), need to create different applet versions with different dlls for x86 and x64. Have you checked if the x86 or x64 dll needed depends on the JRE (32bit or 64bit) or solely on the OS architecture? May be depends if the JRE is 32 or 64 bit, regarding is installed in a 32 or 64 bit Windows (I mean, 32bit JRE installed in Windows 7 x64 may require x86 dlls).

Comment: Thanks for that idea, I'll create two applets, is easier than anything else, about dlls versions, in OS x64, has JRE 32 and yet gave me a error on RXTXcomm.jar inside applet because was x86, and in JRE, I had put .dll and .jar x64. Having two applets resolved my problem. Thanks again.